# Map with political borders similar to google charts, "clickable" countries

Tags: api, dictionary, country

I'd like to add a map of countries to my website where the user can choose a specific country by clicking on it. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/map_charts.html has the looks i want, but it's not possible to underlay the countries with links, afaik(Besides lacking pan/zoom, nice to have). The interactive map(Geo Map) allows more options but it's based on flash which i'd like to avoid(Not sure if links would be possible anyway).

I've played with shapefiles/polylines and google-maps but thats too complex(Lots of data for the polylines, far too much for the simple functionality i need).

Do you know of alternatives which are similarly easy to implement as the google-api-options?

Thx
Christian

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a client-side imagemap? When you say pan/zoom, is this real-time pan/zoom, or you click a button and the page reloads a new map?

Comment: Imagemap would not have been enough, as i need to generate parts of the map from a db. Solved it with SVG in the meanwhile, not perfect but good enough.

Answer (score 4):

I would, if I may, suggest to check out [Highmaps](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo), from the people behind [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) (myself included). It's 100% Javascript based, and designed to get you up and going with very little effort. You can easily implement your own click-based events.

Highmaps is free for non-commercial use, works great with mobile browsers (full touch support) and old IE down to IE6. It also has support for advanced dynamic features like drilldown and rich tooltips, and is very customizable.

We supply a [map collection](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata) with over 350 maps, to get you started quickly. The maps are optimized for size to keep things lightweight.

[image: Population history by country]
[image: Drainage basin of the Meuse river]